# How to condense hardcoded jQuery code to smaller generic code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that works perfectly fine because it is hardcoded but extremely large. I would like to simplify this code to make it general and of course smaller. Does anybody know how to do this? Since it is so large I will shrink it down for this question.

```
    var theform1 = $('#form1').find('.state option');        
    var stateForm1 = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.endsWith('-state1'));
    var stateChoice1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateForm1));

    var theform2 = $('#form2').find('.state option');        
    var stateForm2 = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.endsWith('-state2'));
    var stateChoice2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateForm2));

    var theform3 = $('#form3').find('.state option');        
    var stateForm3 = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.endsWith('-state3'));
    var stateChoice3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateForm3));

    if (localStorage.getItem(stateForm1)) {            
        $(theform1).empty();
        $(theform1).val(stateChoice1).append(`<option value="${stateChoice1}">${stateChoice1}</option>`).trigger('window.load');                    
    }; 

    if (localStorage.getItem(stateForm2)) {            
        $(theform2).empty();
        $(theform2).val(stateChoice2).append(`<option value="${stateChoice2}">${stateChoice2}</option>`).trigger('window.load');                    
    };

    if (localStorage.getItem(stateForm3)) {            
        $(theform3).empty(); 
        $(theform3).val(stateChoice3).append(`<option value="${stateChoice3}">${stateChoice3}</option>`).trigger('window.load');

    };
```

The HTML markup is as follows:

```
    <form id="form1" autocomplete="off">
   <select id="country1" class="country" name="country">
    <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
   </select> 
   <select id="state1" class="state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
   </select> 
   <select id="city1" class="city" name="city">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
   </select>
  </form>
  <form id="form2" autocomplete="off">
   <select id="country2" class="country" name="country">
    <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
    </select> 
   <select id="state2" class="state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
   </select> 
   <select id="city2" class="city" name="city">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
   </select>
  </form>
  <form id="form3" autocomplete="off">
   <select id="country3" class="country" name="country">
    <?php include("countryAjaxData.php"); ?> 
   </select> 
   <select id="state3" class="state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select> 
   <select id="city3" class="city" name="city">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option> 
   </select>
  </form>
```

Comment: You can loop through "state1" - "stateX" and append if you find something :) But first lets get rid off jQuery, its to big tbh. But in order to give accurate answers, we need more information about your current code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What more do you need from my code to come up with a workable answer? Thx

Comment: Some logic here doesn't make sense. You are passing an array to `getItem()` for example. Also setting all options in each of the selects to same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this compressed version:

```
$('#form1,#form2,#form3').each(function () {
    var index = this.id.substring(this.id.length - 1, this.id.length);
    var stateForm = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key => key.endsWith('-state' + index));
    var stateChoice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stateForm));

    if (localStorage.getItem(stateForm)) {
        var theform = $(this).find('.state option').empty();

        theform.val(stateChoice)
                .append(`<option value="${stateChoice}">${stateChoice}</option>`)
                .trigger('window.load');
    }
});
```

---

If you have more than 10 forms with the index increasing from 1 to 99 or 999... You can edit the way to name your form id to: `form01` `form02` `form03` or `form001` `form002` `form003`...

Then, because all of the id names start with `form`, you can update the selectors like this:

Changing `$('#form1,#form2,#form3')` to `$('[id^="form"]')`. That selector means: selecting some element(s) which contains the id starts with `form`.

Lastly, if your form id following by 2 digits (`form01`), you update the line to get the index to:

```
var index = this.id.substring(this.id.length - 2, this.id.length);
```

You can do the same way for the ids following by 3 digits (`form001`):

```
var index = this.id.substring(this.id.length - 3, this.id.length);
```

Comment: You're right, but I guess he wants it without jQuery.

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer OP is only asking how to DRY up repetitive code

Comment: Hello @Tan, your code looks very close to what I am looking for but unfortunately it does not quite work.

Comment: A little more background.. the localstorage setItem data is coming from a database dynamically. The issue here is trying to come up with a way to getItem(s) when the page is refreshed. The hardcoded stuff I have works perfectly but it is grotesquely large and takes 5 days for the browser to get through the code lol.

Comment: @kejo lol, I don't have enough information to test here. Maybe you must check it yourself. In my code, you can try `console.log(index)` `console.log(stateForm)` `console.log(stateChoice)`...... step-by-step. Then you will find the *wrong* line

Comment: @Tân your code does not show any errors in the console. It just does not access the correct elements to get them to display on a page refresh.

Comment: @Tân I will play with your code more to see if I can get it to function. If you have anymore ideas please let me know. Thx.

Comment: Hello @Tân your code works! The only problem was it needed to be loaded immediately when the page loaded. I opened your script with: window.load=$(document).ready(function(elem) Thx

Comment: Hello @Tân Does this work for any number of forms or just up to 9 or a different length id due to this line? var index = this.id.substring(this.id.length - 1, this.id.length); If so can this be fixed for any length or more than 9 elements?  thx

Comment: @kejo Yes, there are multiple ways to do that. The easiest way is: You can make your form id leading zero (if the index id < 10, such as: 01, 02, 03...). Then you update that line to `this.id.substring(this.id.length - 2, this.id.length)`. It should work for id 00 - 99

Comment: Hello @Tân, this is  great. Thank you. It works perfect. You are a life saver. I wish I could send you a tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all the `select.state` and get the number from the parent form.

Something like:

```
$('select.state').each(function() {
  const $sel = $(this),
    formNum = $sel.closest('form').attr('id').replace('form', ''),  
    stateForm = Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => key.endsWith(`-state${formNum }`)),
    stateChoice = localStorage.getItem(stateForm);


  if (stateChoice) {
    $sel.append(new Option(stateChoice. stateChoice))
      .val(stateChoice)
      .trigger('window.load');
  }

})
```

Note I changed `filter()` to `find()` for the keys since filter returns an array

Comment: I tried this however it did not function. I also tried to use it with both filter() to find(). Unfortunately neither worked.

Comment: You will need to do some basic debugging. As I mentioned in comments above there are some oddities in this code and without  [mcve] is hard to help more

Comment: true. It can not be reproduced here because data is coming from a database. I guess I will play with the your answer and Tân's answer to see if I can get something to function. If you have any other ideas please let me know. I would hate to have to keep my hardcoded work if I don't have to. Thanks everybody.:)